# Can't access variable after radio select. Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

New to Laravel / Livewire.

I have a component that outputs a radio group, It renders fine.

When I select one of the radio controls I get an error,  "Attempt to read property "id" on array"

Here I pass an array of options from my blade file

```
@livewire('test-options', ['options' => $option])
```

Component

```
class TestOptions extends Component {

public $selected;
public $options;

public function mount($options)
{
   $this->options = $options;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.test-options', [
        'options' => $this->options
    ]);
}
```

component blade

```
<div>

@foreach($options['items'] as $option_items)
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
       <input 
             wire:model="selected" 
             class="custom-control-input" 
             type="radio"
             id="rdio_{{$option_items['0']->id}}_{{$options['option']->id}}">

             <label class="custom-control-label" for="rdio_{{$option_items['0']->id}}_{{$options['option']->id}}">{{$option_items['0']->title}}</label>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, when you select a radio, Livewire is refreshing the component. However, the `$options` array is not being passed again. `mount()` will only run when the component is first rendered.

You are already passing the options into the component, the `$optons` variable does not need to be mounted as it is already loaded and set here:

```php
@livewire('test-options', ['options' => $option])
```

Change your code to:

```php
class TestOptions extends Component {

public $selected;
public $options;


public function render()
{
    
    return view('livewire.test-options', [
        'options' => $this->options
    ]);
}
```

If you're also trying to get a value from the radio input, you'll need to add a value:

```php
<input 
    wire:model="selected" 
    class="custom-control-input" 
    type="radio"
    value="yourvaluehere"
    id="rdio_{{$option_items['0']->id}}_{{$options['option']->id}}">
```

From the docs:
In Livewire components, you use mount() instead of a class constructor __construct() like you may be used to. NB: mount() is only ever called when the component is first mounted and will not be called again even when the component is refreshed or rerendered.

Read more here: [Receiving Parameters](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters)

Comment: It actually turned out to be because i was using a collection and not an array.  The initial render would output the collection fine but when it re rendered for any reason the data was changed to an array.   To fix i simply converted the collection to an array.